# Is there any way to check if a billing/order item actually exists in softlayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

If I have billing item and order item details is there any attribute which tells if the resource actually exists in SL? for eg: virtual guest whether is available or de-provisioned? there might be other resources as well eg: network_vlan etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This REST example may help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/[billing_item_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,cancellationDate,activeFlag]

Method: GET
```

**Where:**

> cancellationDate:
>
> A billing item's cancellation date. A billing item with a cancellation
>   date in the past is not charged on your SoftLayer invoice.
>   Cancellation dates in the future indicate the current billing item is
>   active, but will be cancelled and not charged for in the future. A
>   billing item with a null cancellation date is also considered an
>   active billing item and is charged once every billing cycle.

The response of a canceled billing item would be:

```
{
  "cancellationDate": "2014-05-16T13:53:55-05:00",
  "id": 18450000,
  "activeFlag": false
}
```

**Reference:**
[SoftLayer_Billing_Item](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item)

Comment: what does activeFlag mean here? Can we rely on this for checking existence of a resource? Does activeFlag=False always mean that the device has a cancellation date in past and activeFlag=True mean the device is still active?

Comment: I guess no. I can see billing items with cancellation date in past and activeFlag=True. What does this mean? If the device has been cancelled why is it still active?

Comment: It’s supposed that `activeFlag = 0` tell us that the billing item is canceled. But you have some cases which don’t meet these criteria. We would need to review these cases, and this property won’t help us to know if a billing item is canceled. I tried to find other properties to get a reliable status of a `billing item`, but I was not lucky. 
I can only say that `“cancellationDate” < currentDate` tell us that `billing Item` was already canceled. I only wish I could have been more helpful, sorry.

Comment: Hey thanks this really helps.One last question I had is can cancellation dates change? Specifically when cancellation date is in future. Can user extend duration of his/her device in case cancellation date is in future?

Comment: This method may help you [SoftLayer_Billing_Item::voidCancelService](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/voidCancelService).